# How to access a String from another class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two classes , one is called the `ViewController` which looks like this

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

 let demoURLs = DemoURLs
 let ImgURL = NSURL(string: demoURLs.photoURL)



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

}
```

The `demoURLs.swift` file looks like this

```
  import Foundation

  struct DemoURLs{
  var photoURL = " xyz " }
```

But I get an error. I understand that my method is incorrect. What is the correct way of accessing this string , so that I can use it in an `NSString`? My final aim is to inflate an `imageView` with an image from this URL.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are instantiating the struct is incorrect. Change

```
let demoURLs = DemoURLs
```

to

```
let demoURLs = DemoURLs()  // the () calls init()
```

and you will be able to access the members of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct DemoURLs {
 static var photoURL = " xyz " 
}
```

should do the job.

To read, from any class use:

```
let myString = DemoURLs.photoURL
```

To write:

```
DemoURLs.photoURL = "new name for xyz"
```

Comment: *Not* a good idea to give static methods/properties as a solution to this issue to a beginner. They should first learn how to use the normal ones...